# Webgl flickering in Chrome on Windows x64 with nvidia GPU

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webgl, nvidia

I see a weird flickering of some rendered geometry Chrome on Windows 10 x64 with nVidia chips. I've also tested in in Chrome for Linux, Firefox for both platforms, Android, and with Intel GPU. It works fine everywhere, except the one platform mentioned.

Minimal example looks like this:

Vertex shader:

```glsl
precision mediump float;
smooth out vec2 pointCoord;

const vec2 vertexCoord[] = vec2[](
    vec2(0.0, 0.0),
    vec2(1.0, 0.0),
    vec2(1.0, 1.0),
    vec2(0.0, 0.0),
    vec2(1.0, 1.0),
    vec2(0.0, 1.0)
);

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(vertexCoord[gl_VertexID], 0.0, 1.0);
    pointCoord = vertexCoord[gl_VertexID];
}
```

Fragment shader:

```glsl
precision mediump float;

out vec4 outFragColor;
smooth in vec2 pointCoord;

void main()
{
    outFragColor = vec4(pointCoord, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

GL state:

```js
gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
gl.disable(gl.BLEND);
gl.disable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
gl.depthMask(gl.FALSE);
gl.stencilMask(gl.FALSE);
```

Rendering code:

```js
var mainLoop = function()
{
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
```

Working web page with full code is available [here](https://sergeyext.github.io/sergeyext/flicker.html).

What I see on affected platforms:

[image]

I tried webgl1 context with a vertex attribute, as there is no `gl_VertexID` variable in glsl 100es, and it produces the same result. I also tried to add `glFinish` or `glFlush` at the end of main loop. It reduces flicker frequency, but does not solve the problem.

What is the problem? Is there any undefined behavior in this code, so it works different ways on different platforms? Or is it a bug in Chrome or Angle?

**UPD:**

Following Nabr's answer, I added a VBO bound to enabled vertex attribute, and constructed [another example](https://sergeyext.github.io/sergeyext/flicker_vbo.html) which flickers on my machines.

**UPD2:**

Reported a bug to Chromium project:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=836788

Comment: Using chrome x64 windows 10, no flickering here...

Comment: @J.vanLangen I added some clarification about GPU. Do you use nvidia?

Comment: It's a notebook with a Intel(R) HD Graphics 630 / NVIDIA GeForce 940MX  [This notebook](http://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/dell-laptops-and-notebooks/latitude-5580/spd/latitude-15-5580-laptop/s007l558015us)

Comment: Did you try firefox?

Comment: @J.vanLangen Yes, I tried FF, and it works fine. I have a notebook with both Intel and Nvidia GPUs too, and it works if I run Chrome with Intel GPU, and flickers, if I run it with Nvidia. It's Intel HD Graphics 620 and Nvidia 950M.

Comment: @Sergey hello i found a working solution for me. if i disable the Intel Graphic card in my device manager. The flicker is gone. Give it a try! My problem is that i run an external screen plugged to my HDMI and i guess the bug occurs besource of some Driver issues on this HDMI port (it is just a guess). I have also bigger Issues with other programs that a fickering Webgl, but with that set up everything works fine, except my external Monitor, NVIDIA can't recognize this output, maybe a have to disable the internal Graphic in the BIOS to get the full support, but i ok from here on. Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

no, flicker here. The quad isn't showing at all.

- Chrome 65
- Windows 10
- NVidia GTX 1050

i follow this since months, the implementation from browser (release) to browser and it's platform is different. you can't have a bufferless "shape" crossplatform, my experience.

you on the save side if you bindBuffer, see here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44448514

```js
// added a buffer array 
// note: commented some consolelogs out, it looks nicer on stackoverflow


var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl2");
if (!gl) {
  console.log("Could not get context.");
  throw new Error();
}
var checkError = function() {
  if (gl.getError() != gl.NO_ERROR) {
    console.log("Webgl error.");
    throw new Error();
  }
}

// GL setup
gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
gl.disable(gl.BLEND);
gl.disable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
gl.depthMask(gl.FALSE);
gl.stencilMask(gl.FALSE);

// Shader
var vertexSource = document.getElementById("vertexShader").text;
var vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vertexSource);
gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
// console.log("Vertex log: " + gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader));

var fragmentSource = document.getElementById("fragmentShader").text;
var fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentSource);
gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
// console.log("Fragment log: " + gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader));

var program = gl.createProgram();
gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
gl.linkProgram(program);
// console.log("Link log: " + gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
checkError();
gl.useProgram(program);
var time_loc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "time");

// CHANGED
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
  0.0, 0.0,
  1.0, 0.0,
  1.0, 1.0,
  0.0, 0.0,
  1.0, 1.0,
  0.0, 1.0
]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.bindVertexArray(null);

var tick = 0;

var mainLoop = function(tick) {
  tick *= 0.001;

  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
  gl.uniform1f(time_loc, tick);
  window.requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
```

```css
<style>canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

</style>
```

```html
<script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">#version 300 es 
precision mediump float; 
in vec2 vertexCoord; 
uniform float time; 
smooth out vec2 pointCoord; 
void main() { 

gl_Position = vec4(vec2[](vertexCoord)[ gl_VertexID ], 0.0, 1.0); 

// for testig purposes suffix likely to fail in the past on firefox 56 windows 7 
pointCoord = vec3[3u](vec3(1.f, 1.f*sin(time), 0.f), vec3(0.0), vec3(0.0))[gl_VertexID%int(mod(time,3.))].xy; 

}
</script>
<script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">#version 300 es 
precision mediump float; 
out vec4 outFragColor; 
smooth in vec2 pointCoord; void main() { 
outFragColor = vec4(pointCoord,0.0, 1.0); 
}
</script>
<canvas id="canvas" style="width:100vw;height:100vh;display:block"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I tried to use buffer instead of hard-coded vertex array in vertex shader, and got the same result.

Comment: I added a flickering example with VBO bound: https://sergeyext.github.io/sergeyext/flicker_vbo.html

Comment: Ok. It seems a the error occours, when chrome://gpu/ is set to WebGL2: Hardware accelerated and with smooth interpolation qualifier (default) in GLSL possible fix: https://jsfiddle.net/qdxfLj9q/7/
i don't know, posible floating point javascript - glsl coversation error, it seems that gl.uniform2f(beginPosition, 0.0, 0.0); is not 0.0 when interpolated in
Normalized Device Coordinates. Hope it helps

Comment: Much nicer workaround: https://jsfiddle.net/nabr/au06x7a8/
if you think about it, it makes sense

Comment: The second variant does not solve the issue as it contains an error: `TypeError: Argument 1 of WebGL2RenderingContext.useProgram is not an object.`.  So it just stops the loop, and flickering disappears. If I replace `gl.useProgram(0);` with `gl.useProgram(null);`, it flickers with a bit different frequency. But the first variant seems to work! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My project has similar problem, later I found if I comment the gl.depthMask, there would be no flickering.

My final solution is close the development tool, the flicker will gone then.

Comment: Anyway, it's a bug in ANGLE, so if your case is conceptually different from mine, please report to the related [issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/angleproject/issues/detail?id=2676).